I am trying to find a summary or phrase describing a vacation that is positive for me, fun, and a learning experience
What is an adjective or a phrase I can use that would express me and a friend having a positive vacation or a learning and fun experience during a trip?

I don't think there are any phrases specific to this. You can just say you "had a good time".

What do you mean by "positive vacation" over and above "a learning and fun experience"?

You could say it was enriching. If used to describe something that is normally recreational such as a vacation it would suggest a mixture of learning and enjoyment. Leisure activities in education institutions are sometimes referred to by the noun "enrichment". A similar adjective is transformative, which suggests that any activity resulted in personal growth.
"Enlightening" or "eye-opening" are two other possibilities, but these are sometimes used sarcastically, when 'mincing words', ie avoiding saying something negative.

I don't think "enriching" has any particular implications of "fun". It's really just a hypernym for "learning", imho.

@FumbleFingers Remember the OP is looking for an adjective to describe a vacation. If someone said "my vacation was enriching", I would take that as something that was recreational but had some deeper benefit too.

Well, I think that's only really because elements like "fun", "recreational", "enjoyable" are already implied by "vacation".

Horrible experiences can result in personal growth and development. So "enriching" might be considered a euphemism (like "interesting" can be).

@StuartF I don't really agree with that. I don't think horrible experiences are ever good or directly contribute to growth. One kid gets bullied, they toughen up and go on to be a millionaire; another kid gets bullied and takes their own life. There's no argument for saying horrible experiences result in personal growth. All growth comes from introspection following any kind of life experience.

OP's Query:

What is an adjective or a phrase I can use that would express me and a friend having a positive vacation or a learning and fun experience during a trip?

To describe your experience, here are some phrases and adjectives that capture positivity, fun, and learning:
Phrases:

Dream vacation – A trip to a place you’ve always wanted to visit.
Ultimate getaway – Perfect for a luxurious or ideal trip.
Adventure of a lifetime – Highlights excitement and lasting memories.
Enriching escape – Balances leisure and personal growth.
Fun-filled retreat – Focuses on pure enjoyment.
Inspirational journey – Captures moments of awe and motivation.
Refreshing retreat – Perfect for relaxation and rejuvenation.
Soul-enriching experience – Suggests deep, meaningful fulfillment.

Adjectives

Idyllic – Perfect for serene, picturesque trips.
Invigorating – Suitable for adventurous or refreshing trips.
Inspiring – Adds a sense of awe and motivation.
Enlightening – Ideal for educational and insightful experiences.
Exhilarating – Perfect for thrilling, action-packed adventures.

